# How can i connect android Button to a web page button?

Tags: android, parsing, button, web

Suppose I have some text fields and a button. Can I link that button to pass the text field values to the webpage button on button click in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.Check this example: [How To Post Data From An Android App To a Website](http://webtutsdepot.com/2011/11/15/android-tutorial-how-to-post-data-from-an-android-app-to-a-website/)

**MainActivity:**

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    Button sendButton;     
    EditText msgTextField;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        // make message text field object
        msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
        // make send button object
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    }

    // this is the function that gets called when you click the button
    public void send(View v)
    {
        // get the message from the message text box
        String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

        // make sure the fields are not empty
        if (msg.length()>0)
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yourwebsite.com/yourPhpScript.php");
         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
           msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }

        }
        else
        {
            // display message if text fields are empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

**Server Side Codes:**

```
<?php
// get the "message" variable from the post request
// this is the data coming from the Android app
$message=$_POST["message"]; 
// specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
$filename="androidmessages.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
file_put_contents($filename,$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
// load the contents of the file to a variable
$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);
// display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
echo $androidmessages;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,just wanted to know will that work for any website? I mean if I am not linked directly to the server.

Comment: I'm not sure that working for any website because its using `PHP` code and i dont have any idea about `Php`.But this is an example of using and sending with `POST`.and you should test it and learn the php for how to working this.

Comment: Also some of the interfaces are deprecated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. you can edit it and put the new interfaces on these codes.